# Run set interval when click from another component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

i want to trigger countdown of 60 seconds when user click from another component . so far i didn't find any solution

```
 const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60)
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.Trade.length ,"woking in useeffect ");
    setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(prevState => prevState - 1)
    }, 1000);
 }, [state.Trade.length]);


 // also use without use effect 


    const startCounter = () => { 
  setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(prevState => prevState - 1)
  }, 1000);
 }
if (state.Trade.length!=0) {
  if (seconds==0) return null
  startCounter()
 
}else{
  return null
}
```

it is not working i search a lot but did not find.Thanks

Comment: What is `state.Trade.length` ?

Comment: its a state come from use context when user click length will become 1. and countdown should run for 60 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to clear your interval

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prevState) => {
        if(prevState === 1) clearInterval(intervalId)
        return prevState - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
}, [state.Trade.length]);
```

Comment: useeffect  excuting before state.trade change . when reload it start running and clear interval also not working . hope you will help

Comment: it will alway run at the inital of component. Create a state const `[hasInited, setHasInited] = useState(false)` 
Then you can check `if( hasInited ) { ... setInterval( ... ) ...} else { setHasInited(true) }`

Comment: should i use  useffect in hasInited true condition that what you are saying?

Comment: i want useffect not to excute on intail render infact render only when state.trade.length change . thanks

Comment: what if i click two times its excute again while the previous interval is also working i treid to put condition when trade.length==1 then only excute the useffect else do nothing . its give error "too many renders"

Comment: const [trade, setTrade] = useState(false);
  if (state.Trade.length === 1) {
    console.log("working");
    setTrade(true)
  }   i use trade as useffect dependecy

Comment: `i want useffect not to excute on intail render infact render only when state.trade.length change . thanks`
useEffect wont work that way

Comment: `what if i click two times its excute again while the previous interval is also working i treid to put condition when trade.length==1 then only excute the useffect else do nothing . its give error "too many renders"`
if you want to refresh the time after the 2nd click, create a ref to store the `intervalId` :

Comment: i dont want to refresh the time inface when second click do nothing previous interval is working and the time is start decrasing no matter user click 100 time just start decreasing on first time and after that nothing should happen.

Comment: thanks in advance thats the requiremnt i need hopes its you understand and help

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` will trigger when `state.Trade.length` changes.

You probably need to have a dependency to `seconds`.

Something like this:

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60)
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.Trade.length ,"woking in useeffect ");
    setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(prevState => prevState - 1)
    }, 1000);
 }, [seconds]);
```

Note that this has 2 issues:

1. Linters will complain about not having `state.Trade.length` as dep, but you're just using this to console the value
2. `setInterval` just uses the time as a hint. If you want a proper countdown. You should measure the time between 2 invocations and adjust the 1000ms interval.

Comment: i try this but this is not working as how i change my first update  seconds ?i have to pass dep that is change when user click .

Comment: You are setting seconds state inside useEffect and passing that same state inside the dependency array, this will cause an infinite redering.

Comment: It is not an infinite rendering, as the state update is done at a later time. This will decrease seconds at about 1 per second frequency.

Comment: yes it cause infinte loop but you can set condition when seconds ==0 clear the interval Or return null in use effect .but this sol in  not working as how i update seconds first time

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some pointer to try based on the question you are asking & the code you have given for reference.

1. Dont pass any dependency in the useEffect as it will be executed only when the dependency changes. Keep the dependency array blank then it will work like componentDidMount().
2. You can simply use setTimeOut() function to wait for 60 seconds when the component is mounted and then do your logic in that.
3. I dont recommend using setSeconds in useEffect when its dependency is seconds  variable itself. This might cause an infinite render (as given in one of the answer here).

Edit 1: So what I am doing below is changing the state variable to 1 on a button click to simulate your scenario. Then in one useEffect I am setting an interval to do -1 for the `seconds` variable which is 5 here but you can make it 60. On ummount, the interval will be cleared. The second useEffect is just logging when the `seconds` changes every second.

```
const[state,setState]=useState(0)
const[seconds, setSeconds]=useState(5)
useEffect(()=>{
    let secondsInterval;
    if(state===1){
        secondsInterval=setInterval(()=>{
            setSeconds(prev=>prev-1)
        },1000)
    }
    return()=>clearInterval(secondsInterval)
},[state])

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Time remaining: "+seconds);
},[seconds])
```

Comment: the point is that i dont want to excute use effect when componentdidmount its excute when user click on button from another component  thats why i have to pass some dependency .

Comment: ok. then pass it but dont use setInterval and create the seconds state instead just write a set TimeOut for 60 seconds. Do you want to show the timer on the screen as well?

Comment: const[state,setState]=useState(0);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(state===1){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("Here is the logic");
            },1000)
        }
    },[state])

//This should work after one second. you can change it to 60 seconds. WIth the button click I am changing the state to 1.

Comment: i want to show timer on the screen as well and with set timout it will delay the function which i dont think is my need

Comment: @Zeeshan See my edit above with 2 useEffects.

Comment: its not working because seconds is not updating due to clearintrval.

Comment: thanks for your effort its my pleausre you are helping me